# Java - Making inherited variables PRIVATE

Tags: java, inheritance, access-modifiers, private-members

I need to make my inherited instance variables private; is this possible?

IE, Superclass "Entity" has an int instance variable "health".

How can subclass "Zombie" (Extends "Entity") inherit the health variable from Entity, and have it private? I don't want other classes to be able to directly access the health variable, I want set and get methods for it.

Tell me if I wasn't specific enough; any help appreciated.

Comment: When you override a method it is not possible to reduce the visibility of a method. `Public -> Private` you are reducing the visibility.

Answer (score 3):

Simply : you can't.

This would break the contract of the superclass. Your class, being an `Entity`, exposes, like its superclass, a field named `health`. If you had the ability to make it private, all code using this field in instances of `Entity` (including instances of subclasses of Entity) would break with your class...

If you can, change the superclass (ie `Entity`) to make the field private. That's the common practice.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot decrease the visibility of any instance variable or method of the super class in your subclass..

Suppost you have super class with a `public method`.. And, suppose you were allowed to decrease the visibility to `private` in sub class..

Then see what's happens when you create object like this, and access that method of super class: -

```
SuperClass obj = new SubClass();
obj.pubMethod();
```

Now, **at compile time**, compiler sees that method `pubMethod()` is public in `SuperClass`, it will allow the access.. Note it does not check for the `instance type` on the RHS..

Now, **at runtime**, when JVM checks that the instance is of `SubClass`, then the actual method it would try to invoke will be searched in the `SubClass`..

But wait.. Did you see what happened when `JVM` went to search for `pubMethod` in `SubClass` that you made `private`..  **BOoooooMMM** --  A Crash..

That's why it is not allowed..

So, you cannot make it private..

From [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/classes.html) Section - 8.4.8.3:  -

> The access modifier (§6.6) of an overriding or hiding method must
>   provide at least as much access as the overridden or hidden method, or
>   a compile-time error occurs. In more detail:
>
> - If the overridden or hidden method is public, then the overriding or    hiding method must be public; otherwise, a compile-time error
>     occurs.
> - If the overridden or hidden method is protected, then the overriding    or hiding method must be protected or public; otherwise,
>     a    compile-time error occurs.
> - If the overridden or hidden method has default (package) access, then    the overriding or hiding method must not be private;
>     otherwise, a    compile-time error occurs.

Answer (score 2):

Make the variable private in the superclass and let all subclasses use accessor methods.

A second choice would be to make it package-private and arrange for those classes to which you want to deny access to be in another package. This would make sense if your Zombie is especially close to Entity (shares many internals) whereas other classes are more loosely coupled to their superclass.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add restrictions to an instance variable in a subclass, i.e. of `health` is `protected` in `Enitity` it cannot be `private` in `Zombie` (you can make it `public`).

However, you can make health `private` in `Entity` and define a `protected` getter and setter there. Subclasses can use these methods.

Comment: Perfect, that's the answer I was looking for. Thanks!